# VSTS ARM Deploy - Array parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am having troubles passing an array of point to site certificates using a VSTS task to deploy the template.

This is my parameter:

```
"pointToSiteRootCertificates": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue": [
            {
                "name": "cert1",
                "properties":{
                    "PublicCertdata" : "base64EncodedPublicCert"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "cert2",
                "properties":{
                    "PublicCertdata" : "base64EncodedPublicCert"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

This is my resource:

```
{
            "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways",
            "name": "[variables('virtualGatewayName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('gatewayPublicIPName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('gatewaySubnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', variables('gatewayPublicIPName'))]"
                            }
                        },
                        "name": "vnetGatewayConfig"
                    }
                ],
                "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('gatewaySku')]",
                    "tier": "[parameters('gatewaySku')]"
                },
                "gatewayType": "Vpn",
                "vpnType": "[parameters('vpnType')]",
                "enableBgp": "false",
                "vpnClientConfiguration": {
                    "vpnClientAddressPool": {
                        "addressPrefixes": [
                            "[parameters('vpnClientAddressPoolPrefix')]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "vpnClientRootCertificates": "[parameters('pointToSiteRootCertificates')]"
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my overriden parameter:

```
-pointToSiteRootCertificates [{"name": "root", "properties": {"PublicCertData": "$(public-cert-root)"}}, {"certificateName": "root-prod-sub", "properties": {"PublicCertData":"$(public-cert-root-sub)"}}]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": "InvalidRequestFormat",
"message": "Cannot parse the request.",
"details": []
}
}
```

I have tried many things, but was not able to get this working. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the result if you don't override the parameter? What's the template like after override the parameter?

Comment: The content of pointToSiteRootCertificates in parameter file is different with the override parameter, so which one is right?

Comment: I have update my question, the default value was indeed wrong.

Comment: What's the result if you don't override the parameter?